# assigning the string value of the variable that holds an object to the object as a property

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

I am looking for a way to do this in javascript.

```
const desired_name = Handle();
print(desired_name.type) //"desired_name";
```

does window / document / the global space have a array/stack/queue structure that can be parsed for the last variable name declared? - does that exist?

Comment: No, why would you want this? You can do something like `function define(n, v) { window._sn ??= []; window._sn.push(n); return v; }` and then do `const foo = define('foo', 3);`

Comment: No, this is impossible. And you shouldn't be doing this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: 100% impossible?

Comment: What is `handle`?

Comment: @altruios Yes, 100% impossible with the code you wrote. If you tell us more about your actual code, we might be able to advise you on alternatives.

Comment: call to class constructor @Barmar

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have much in the way of function introspection.

Comment: @altruios That's `Handle()`, I was asking about `handle` in `handle.type`.

Comment: @barmar that's a derp. fixing :)

Comment: There's no link from objects to the variables that refer to them.

Comment: References just go one way.